# Python-tkinter: Problema introduciendo datos en una tabla con Entrys

Tags: python, tkinter

Soy nuevo programando, y llevo tiempo intentando resolver este problema (para un juego de manager de ciclismo online) pero no lo consigo. Quiero crear una tabla con entrys, donde en cada celda aparezca un valor, pero que pueda ser modificado por el usuario posteriormente.
Para una sola celda lo logro hacer, pero al hacer el bucle, lo más que consigo es que todas las celdas tengan el mismo valor (el último de la lista). LO más probable es que sea fácil encontrar el problema :P

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
frameTabla=Frame(root)
frameTabla.pack()

#creo el valor para introducir en los Entry
valor=StringVar()
#"y" es el nombre de las columnas
y=["Nombre","Edad","Res","Spr","Mon","LLa","Pavés","Tec","Des","Col","Agres","TT","Teq","Exp","€","Salud","Form","Carreras","Puntos"]
#"valores" es el nombre, edad, etc del ciclista
valores=["Byers",23,76,50,11,82,100,73,67,95,12,9,51,21,1037,86,99,13,198]

filas = 1 #una fila sola, para probar solo 1 ciclista de momento
columnas = len(y)

#Inserto los nombres de las columnas con Label (la 1ª más ancha para el nombre)
for j in range(columnas):
    if j==0:

 Label(frameTabla,width=10,text=y[j],justify="center").grid(row=0,column=j)
    else:
        Label(frameTabla,width=3,text=y[j],justify="center").grid(row=0,column=j)

#y ahora intento introducir los datos            
for i in range(filas): 
    for j in range(columnas):
        if j==0:
            valor.set(valores[j])


  Entry(frameTabla,width=20,justify="center",textvariable=valor).grid(row=i+1, column=j)
        else:  
            valor.set(valores[j])

                Entry(frameTabla,width=4,justify="center",textvariable=valor).grid(row=i+1, column=j)


root.mainloop()
```

Y como ya comenté, el resultado es una tabla donde todas las celdas tienen el nº 198, el último de los valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema esta en la variable `valor`, debes recrearla cada vez que la llamas:  `valor=StringVar()` pues para cada vuelta debe resetear su valor, quedando de esta forma:

```
for i in range(filas): 
    for j in range(columnas):
        if j==0:
            valor=StringVar()  # <--- RESETEANDO  PARA EL NUEVO VALOR
            valor.set(valores[j])
            Entry(frameTabla,width=20,justify="center",textvariable=valor).grid(row=i+1, column=j)
        else:
            valor=StringVar()  # <--- RESETEANDO  PARA EL NUEVO VALOR
            valor.set(valores[j])
            Entry(frameTabla,width=4,justify="center",textvariable=valor).grid(row=i+1, column=j)
```

Comment: Gracias. ¿y cual es el motivo por el que se debe hacer así? No me parece intuitivo tener que resetear en cada vuelta del bucle, cuando parece que lo lógico es sobreescribir. Lo pregunto por si me encuentro algo similar en otra ocasión.

Comment: En el caso del StringVar sucede esto , el problema es que llamas a una instancia y esa instancia se almacena en memoria(ocupa una direccion de memoria) y para cada vuelta el valor va cambiando en esa dicha direccion por eso el obtuviste el ultimo valor en todas las casillas; en realidad cada que va realizando el ciclo el dato nuevo se reemplaza por el anterior. Es porque para cada Entry le corresponde un unico StringValor (ya que lo declaraste solo una vez y lo utilizaste n veces ocupando una misma direccion de memoria)por eso el valor se re reemplazaba cada vez que hacia un ciclo y

Comment: obtuviste el ultimo valor, porque normalmente ya se estableces una cantidad de StringVar para sus correspondientes Entry pero como en tu caso vos eatabas creandolo mediante un ciclo, por eso debias crrar una nueva instancia para cada Entry porque estabas utilizando un StringVar para "n" Entry.(A cada Entry le corresponde una instancia StringVar)